# How to create this brownie texture on geometry nodes?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, geometry

I just wanted to know if there's a way to create this type of texture and make it look realistic? any feedback or direction I should head to? thanks!

[image: pic of brownie]

Comment: did you ever use geometry nodes?

Comment: Hi Eugenio :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck? (imho such texture could be done with displacement)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Geometry nodes isn't probably the best tool for this.
But displacement might be a good start.

One *noise texture* for larger holes, another for bumpy surface.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow this was very helpful, thanks for this :D!!!

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project ;)

Comment: thank you @Jachym Michal :)! quick question, if besides these noise texture nodes combined by a math node, I want also add like bump to it. I'm planning to reuse this texture for rise cookie, and is similar with the holes but on top of that, there's a layer of rise pieces (deformed pieces) on top. Should I make it with noise texture and combining again with the resulting initial math? or do you think with a particles system with emission (collection) that contains deformed pieces already created covering the surface will help to create a better effect? thanks for your time to respond!

Comment: Hi :). I'd try both ways and see. But yes, you can combine any number of textures using more add nodes. If you get stuck, feel free to ask a new question ;)

Comment: posted ^^ thanks!

Comment: +1 ...now i am hungry.... :(